# Отличие передачи указателя от передачи массива в функцию

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели

Чем отличаются эти блоки кода ?
В первом передаем указатель на первый элемент массива, а во втором ?

1)

```
void FillArray(int *arr, const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
}
```

2)

```
void FillArray(int arr[], const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае разницы нет, как я понимаю. И во втором случае тоже передаем указатель на первый элемент массива. Синтаксис разный, смысл один и тот же: в функцию в качестве аргумента передаётся указатель на тип int.

В общем случае отличия, возможно, есть. Второй вариант использует объявление параметра, как массива. В итоге оно превратится в объявление параметра-указателя (т.е. в первый вариант), но с ограничением: размер массива должен быть больше нуля.